# EPROM memory - the theoretical possibility of recovering data from memory after erasing the exposure with ultraviolet light?

Tags: reference-materials, eprom, recovery

I have a small question.

We have a [EPROM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPROM) memory.

Is there a theoretical possibility of recovering data from memory after deleting with ultraviolet light?

Is this theoretically possible?
Or maybe it is impossible?

Anyone can give a source/reference (eg. scientific publication)?

Comment: 0%.................  Unless all your data is 1's.

Comment: Well, you've linked a Wikipedia article... which cites a whole lot of articles. [Here's some good research](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~sps32/DataRem_CHES2005.pdf) on what you're trying to find. These articles aren't hard to find. I typed in on Google, "Data remnants of EPROM memory after erasure".

Comment: @KingDuken A nice read.

Answer (score 3):

Dr. Sergei Skorobogatov from the Computer Science department of the University of Cambridge [has written a rather sufficient article on this matter](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~sps32/DataRem_CHES2005.pdf). In his research, he writes:

> Even after an erase operation, the transistor does not return fully to its initial state, thereby allowing the attacker to distinguish between previously programmed and not programmed transistors, and thus restore information from erased memory.

in his abstract.

You may further investigate why in this research article as he provides physical depth of an EPROM module along with his methods of experimentations.

Answer (score 1):

The Mathematical Theory of Communication, by Claude Shannon and Warren Weaver, is a good place to start.

A programmed EPROM has a signal (in the conductivity of its memory
cell transistors) that can be read out, and has a large signal-to-noise
ratio.   Erasure reduces the signal, until the logarithm of the signal-plus-noise
to noise ratio becomes zero.

There's a way to identi fy, from any given erasure efficacy, the amount
of information in the EPROM after erasure (Shannon gives the formula,
and Weaver explains it).

The usual circuitry in the EPROM will call all the erased bits '1' (all the words 'FF')
because that defines the erasure level that is complete (in the 
hardware data sheet), so you can't expect the EPROM to simply plug into
a socket and read out the erased parts.  In that sense, there's no
practical way to read the erased data, because the EPROM internal
readout amplifiers have a threshold below which all inputs are interpreted
as '1', which is the erased state as well as the unprogrammed state.

Even with signal-to-noise ratios in the zero range, however, one might
use
extraordinary readout procedures (like electron microprobing with
power applied to the opened-up package of the EPROM).
In theory, that allows one to
identify all the erased bits, and get more than half of those
identifications right.   Guessing, one expects exactly half
right, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say your chances of recovering all of the data is very low.

If the device was insufficiently erased, you can lower Vcc and read data that was only partially erased.  The problem is that some bits will erase faster than others.  So whatever you read is unlikely to be correct.

I have intentionally created devices that were erased incompletely to illustrate the concept of sufficient erase margin.  But I was never successful in creating one that gave back the exact data that was programmed.  Similarly, I've created devices with insufficient program margin that read correctly at 5V but had programmed bits with insufficient programming margin read as unprogrammed at high Vcc.